# Errors with wxMaxima on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded wxMaxima on ubuntu 17.04 zesty only using one command

```
 sudo apt-get install wxmaxima
```

after opening it though I got the following errors:

```
 loadfile: failed to load /usr/share/wxMaxima/wxmathml.lisp
-- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
loadfile: failed to load /usr/share/wxMaxima/wxmathml.lisp
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
```

How can I fix them?
 Should I install maxima as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this PPA:
https://code.launchpad.net/~peterpall/+archive/ubuntu/wxmaxima-nightlies

and reinstall wxmaxima

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterpall/wxmaxima-nightlies
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wxmaxima
```

Comment: could you explain why this could help?